# Create view using tables from differing databases on a server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, dynamic-sql

I need to create a view that pulls data from multiple databases on a server. I've done this by hard coding the database names (db1.schema.table), but I need it to be more dynamic. This view needs to be available to run on multiple servers that have 1 or more databases. The database and table structures are all the same.

I know I can get the data using a cursor and dynamic SQL, but that does not result in the view I need for reporting in another software program.

If it makes more sense, I want to Union data from the same table in multiple databases into one view, however, the number and name of different databases will be different on different servers. Can this be done without hard coding the views on each server?

Comment: You'll probably get better answers if you post the code you've written so far, along with why the results are incorrect. Writing this out as a word problem isn't really helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure you can accomplish it in a view but you could put in a stored procedure and use sp_msforeachdb to accomplish that.  You'll need to write some dynamic sql and write code for which databases to skip .

Comment: @indiri sp_msforeachdb has a known bug that may result in all databases not being returned.  [Bad habits to kick : relying on undocumented behavior](https://sqlblog.org/2020/05/12/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to hard-code the view on each server.  But you can write a stored procedure to recreate the view on-demand.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought, just wanted to ask here to see if there was some possibility I didn't know about.